# How to find the total rows in a database

Tags: mysql, arrays, vb.net

I had a look at the other topics here on getting row numbers but couldn't fully understand them. All I need is a way of getting the total number of rows.

I have the following code that reads each row and populates a listbox, however as I want to assign that rows value to an array. I need to know the row number so I can use a 2-dimentional array, where each row data is stored separately in the array.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM bbs_test.test"
command = New MySqlCommand(query, Sqlconn)
reader = command.ExecuteReader

While reader.Read
     arraynames = reader.GetString("data_array")
     ListBox_displayarray.Items.Add(arraynames)
End While
```

Is there a way to get the total row number.

Please could any help

Thank you

After looking at the suggestions I have tried it out and this is how my code looks like

```
Sqlconn.Open()   
Dim querycount As String

querycount = "SELECT count(*) FROM bbs_test.test"
command = New MySqlCommand(querycount, Sqlconn)
reader = command.ExecuteReader

While reader.Read
     MessageBox.Show(reader.GetString("data_array"))
End While
```

The following error occurs 
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: Could not find specified column in results"

I checked and made sure the name of the column is data_array.
Could anyone help me please.

Comment: You need to run SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bbs_test.test; Which will return the total number of rows within bbs_test.test :) As for the followup info, I'm having difficulty following what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have tried that. When I run the code to display the value in a integer type, I get an error stating it cannot convert string type to an integer type. I tried using CInt(query) to change to an integer I cannot.  Do you know of a way to change it to an integer.  Thank you

Comment: try   MessageBox.Show(reader.GetString(0))

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bbs_test.test"
```

This will fetch the count of total number of rows in your table

Answer (score 0):

you need to run the query,

```
queryCount = "SELECT count(*) FROM bbs_test.test"
command = New MySqlCommand(queryCount, Sqlconn)
var totalRow = command.ExecuteScalar()
```

In variable totalRow , you have your no. of rows.

Comment: I have tried, but an error occurs stating "Could not find specified column in results".  I know that the column name is  data_array. Is there another reason why this message appeared. Also, for this I assumed you have taken querycount and count to be both strings.

Comment: This query does not return a column called `data_array`, it returns a single integer value - nothing else!

Comment: @Arran Rai : I have updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: @bishangupta The OP asked for VB, not C#. In which case the last line would be `Dim totalRows as Integer = CInt(command.ExecuteScalar())`.